# Oracle - JSON_OBJECT - ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 18c database.

For one of my Query, I am trying generate JSon from 3 level of tables.

```
pages_tbl 
    page_regions_tbl 
        region_items_tbl
```

For that I have prepared below query. But it is giving me error `ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000)`

```
SELECT 
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'page' VALUE p.name, 
      'regions' VALUE(
        SELECT 
          JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
              'region' VALUE r.name, 
              'items' VALUE(
                SELECT 
                  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                    JSON_OBJECT(
                      'item_name' VALUE i.item_name, 'item_value' VALUE i.item_value
                    ) RETURNING CLOB
                  ) 
                FROM region_items_tbl i
               WHERE i.region_id = r.region_id
                 AND i.enabled = 1
              )
            ) RETURNING CLOB
          ) 
        FROM page_regions_tbl r 
       WHERE r.page_id = p.page_id
         AND r.enabled = 1
      ) 
    ) RETURNING CLOB
  ) 
 FROM pages_tbl p 
WHERE p.category_id = 10150
  AND p.enabled = 1
```

I have already written `RETURNING CLOB` so I was expecting smooth result but getting error. Can any one point me out what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this query

Comment: what version of oracle are you running on?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Oracle 18.3

Comment: I found a suggestion on oracle knowledge base Doc ID 2354511.1 . Do you have access to oracle support?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't have access to support account.

Comment: OK. I'll post as an answer.   Try it out, and I can remove the answer if it does not work.

Comment: Same issue i am facing. If anyone has solution please share

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the same result (still failing, even with RETURNING CLOB added to every JSON_OBJECT), however I've found that you also need to add RETURNING CLOB to your JSON_ARRAYAGG functions (but not your JSON_ARRAY functions, if you had any). This fixed the issue for me and it displays the returned data as "(CLOB)", but expands to the *real* data when you click into it.

Answer (score 1):

add RETURNING CLOB before all JSON_OBJECT's closing brackets

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html

JSON_returning_clause

Use this clause to specify the type of return value. One of :

VARCHAR2 specifying the size as a number of bytes or characters. The default is bytes. If you omit this clause, or specify the clause without specifying the size value, then JSON_ARRAY returns a character string of type VARCHAR2(4000). Refer to VARCHAR2 Data Type for more information. Note that when specifying the VARCHAR2 data type elsewhere in SQL, you are required to specify a size. However, in the JSON_returning_clause you can omit the size.

CLOB to return a character large object containing single-byte or multi-byte characters.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.